# How to acess object of json in node.js using node-fetch

Tags: node.js, fetch, node-modules, fetch-api, rest

My code

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
fetch(`http://api.qrserver.com/v1/read-qr-code/?fileurl=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.discordapp.net%2Fattachments%2F830357710473658368%2F872712396723081236%2Fqrcode.png`).then(res => res.json()).then(jsondata => console.log(jsondata))
```

Api response

```
[{"type":"qrcode","symbol":[{"seq":0,"data":"test1","error":null}]}]
```

I want to get the  "data":"test1" but how?

Comment: `jsondata[0]["symbol"][0]["data"]`?

Comment: That is how you get your `"data": "test1"`... it was your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get `"test1"` from this `JSON`:

```js
[
   {
      "type":"qrcode",
      "symbol":[
         {
            "seq":0,
            "data":"test1",
            "error":null
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

So you can do:

```js
let firstResponseArrayElement = jsonData[0]; // {"type":"qrcode","symbol":[{"seq":0,"data":"test1","error":null}]}
let symbolValue = firstResponseArrayElement["symbol"]; // [{"seq":0,"data":"test1","error":null}]
let firstSymbol = symbolValue[0]; // {"seq":0,"data":"test1","error":null}
let symbolData = firstSymbol["data"]; // "test1"
```

To understand better I would recommend to read JSON data format: https://www.json.org/json-en.html